# Python: iterate transfer cookies from requests session to Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem regarding the transfer of cookies from a requests session to the Selenium WebDriver.

As WebDriver I use `chromedriver`.

```
for c in r.cookies:
    driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value,'path': c.path, 'expiry': c.expires})

driver.get("https://www.bstn.com/de/cart")
```

Now it seems like the iteration doesn't transfer all cookies. I can see this because my cart at bstn.com is empty.

When I code it like following:

```
for c in r.cookies:
    driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value,'path': c.path, 'expiry': c.expires})
    driver.get("https://www.bstn.com/de/cart")
```

The browser calls the website approx 10 times. In the end, I can access my cart and see the carted item.

Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong with the iteration? In my opinion, the first code example is the right one. Which is weird. Maybe I need to call the website first?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Max.

Comment: Hi! How is going? Did my answer fix your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the refresh of the page after setting up cookies:

```
driver.refresh()
```

And you should see the changes.

Your code will look like this:

```
for c in r.cookies:

    driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value,'path': c.path, 'expiry': c.expires})

driver.refresh()
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot! :)